# How to unzip a file and sub files using powershell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to unzip a file, this file has 3 more files inside it which are also zipped. I would like to  unzip them all into one single folder. I have unzip script which i am calling from my main script.
My main script is as follows

```
$localPath = 'C:\Projects\Deployments\'
$latestDir = $(get-childitem $localPath | sort lastwritetime | select -Last 1).FullName
$Unzip = 'C:\Projects\unzip'
.\unzip.ps1 $latestDir $Unzip 



    $src = $unzip + "\"
    #The below two zip file are contained within 1 more main zip file which is called package
    $TabletzipPath = $Unzip +  "tablet-webdeploy-3.0.zip"
    $AdminzipPath =  $Unzip +  "admin-webdeploy-3.0.zip"


    $Date = Get-Date
    $folder_date = $Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd_HHmm")
    $tempPath = 'C:\_Temp' + $folder_date
    if (!(Test-Path -path $tempPath)) 
    {
        New-Item $tempPath -type directory
    }   

    .\unzip.ps1 $TabletzipPath $tempPath
    .\unzip.ps1 $AdminzipPath $tempPath
```

My unzip file is as follows

```
function Expand-ZIPFile($file, $destination)
{
$shell = new-object -com shell.application
$zip = $shell.NameSpace($file)
foreach($item in $zip.items())
{
    $shell.Namespace($destination).copyhere($item)
}
}

Expand-ZIPFile -File $args[0] -Destination $args[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

The contents of the zip file are exposed in your function variable $zip.items(). You can filter it to find anything ending in .zip, add that to an array then once the main unzip is complete, if the array exists you can use it to continue unzipping things. You can call the function into your current scope by dot sourcing it to see the variable.

```
($Zip.items()) | select -expand name | ? {$_ -like "*.zip"}
```

Alternatively you could always complete your script, scan the extract directory for things ending in .zip and then process them if any are found.